present vs present perfect, what's the difference here?

#1 I won’t go on holiday unless I save some money.

Here's the sentence. And I think I'm not sure what exactly it means.
I think using present perfect makes me understand, but I'm not sure why "save(present)" was used

#2 I will go on holiday if I have saved some money.


#3 I won't go on holiday if I haven't saved some money.


#4 I won't go on holiday unless I have saved some money.

Are #1,2,3,4 the same effective meaning?

Yes, they all mean the same.  Unless I save some money between now and the holiday season, or unless I have saved some money when that time comes.

Thank you very much!
In many case, I feel we can use present tense with duration. for example,

when I work here for 5 years, I will be able to get a pay rise
when I have worked here for 5 years, I will be able to get a pay rise
when I have been working here for 5 years, I will be able to get a pay rise


No - in this case (1) isn't a valid sentence - although If I work here for five years I will get a pay rise  (implying at the end of that time) would be OK.

#1 I won’t go on holiday unless I save some money implies the speaker currently needs to decide whether or not to save some money in order to affect future holiday plans, and/or currently needs to start saving if he does want to go. #4 I won't go on holiday unless I have saved some money defers / obviates the decision. In the second case, perhaps the speaker ends up saving some money and going on holiday even if he never explicitly decided to commit to such a plan; maybe he just didn't spend all his income, for no particular reason.

All four sentences convey that saving is necessary before the holiday. Sentence 1, 3, and 4 are similar because it uses "will not" i.e. the speaker is willing to cancel going for a holiday if enough money is not saved. But sentence 2 has positive sense "will go". which shows eagerness to go i.e.it means that the speaker will somehow save money for the holidays

#1. "I won’t go on holiday unless I save some money."


Implies future saving must occur before the holiday.
Uses present simple ("save") for a condition to be fulfilled.
First conditional structure (probable condition) : "if + present simple, will + infinitive" (implied). If past tense"saved" making the sentence a hypothetical condition.


#2. "I will go on holiday if I have saved some money."


Similar meaning to #1.
Present Perfect ("have saved") is used to show the condition to be completed to go for a holiday.


#3. "I won't go on holiday if I haven't saved some money."


It has similar meaning, but double negation ("won't" + "haven't") may cause confusion.


#4. "I won't go on holiday unless I have saved some money."


Same meaning as #2, It shows completed saving  as a condition to go on a holiday.


To me it seems you're confusing idiom and syntax with grammar. Broadly, the four given sentences do not convey anything usefully similar.

This is not about tenses; not 'present vs present perfect' nor any other.
#1 'I won’t go on holiday unless I save some money' could never work, but that's due far more to context and idiom, than grammar or tense.
Simply, example #1 needed not '… won’t…' but 'can't…'. Even that runs into the difference between 'need…' and 'want…' and I suggest that's way off topic here.
Quite separately, not 'unless I save…' but 'until I have saved…' and even then, more rightly 'until I have saved enough…' Does that much work for you?
Any tense might 'help…' but how could any tense 'make…' you understand?
'… save (present)' looks like a simple mistake. Doesn't that work for you?
